# Files uploaded through Manage Attachments changes filename - how to keep original name?

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, third-party-module, file-upload, filesystem

Is it possible to deactivate the auto renaming of file uploaded through manage attachments?

e.g. test.PNG is getting saved as File-1540823510.png on the webserver.

Is there a way to deactivate this in the backend, or do I have to change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the "Manage Attachments" is a magento core functionality, but it is acutally a extension called `Uni_Fileuploader`. Thanks to @Haim, for the hint! I changed the function `saveAction` from:

```
public function saveAction() {
    $filedata = array();
    $uploadedFile = 'uploaded_file';
    $_helper = Mage::helper('fileuploader');
    if (!empty($_FILES[$uploadedFile]['name'])) {
        try {
            $ext = $_helper->getFileExtension($_FILES[$uploadedFile]['name']);
            $fname = 'File-' . time() . $ext;
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($uploadedFile);
            #$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array("txt", "csv", "htm", "html", "xml", "css", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rtf", "ppt", "pdf", "swf", "flv", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "wav", "mp3", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png","zip"));

            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            ...
```

to:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    $filedata = array();
    $uploadedFile = 'uploaded_file';
    $_helper = Mage::helper('fileuploader');

    $fileNameWithExtension = $_FILES[$uploadedFile]['name'];
    $fileNameWithoutExtension = pathinfo($fileNameWithExtension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $fileSize = $_FILES[$uploadedFile]['size'];

    if (!empty($fileNameWithExtension) && $fileSize > 0) {
        try {
            $ext = $_helper->getFileExtension($fileNameWithExtension);
            $fname = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileNameWithoutExtension . $ext);
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($uploadedFile);

            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array("txt", "csv", "htm", "html", "xml", "css", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rtf", "ppt", "pdf", "swf", "flv", "avi", "wmv", "mov", "wav", "mp3", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png","zip"));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            ...
```

Now the original name stays unchanged after the upload.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the WYIWYG editor and that you're trying to overwrite an existing image but you don't want the upload to change your image name, you can always the delete the original image first and then upload your new image.
Since you first delteed teh original image, when you upload the new image it will keep the filename as intended.
[image: delete image through WYSIWYG]

Comment: No, I am talking about "Catalog -> Manage Attachments".

Comment: @Black That's a custom extension - what extension are you using?

Comment: thats no extension, thats magento default I think.

Comment: what version of Magento are you on?

Comment: I am on 1.9.3.0

Comment: here's a clean Magento 1.9.3.8 screenshot - no such menu item http://prntscr.com/lbuhsd

Comment: oh you are right, it is indeed an extension :/ thanks for the hint. So I guess I will have to check the extensions configuration or code.

Comment: :) what extension is it - just curious

Comment: It is from the namespace "Uni" and is called "Fileuploader". You can't change the behaviour in the settings.

Comment: found it https://github.com/MaWoScha/Unicode_FileUploader

Comment: It is turned off, but it still works. Weird extension.

Comment: where is it turned off? in system=>configuration?

Comment: look here on line 90 https://github.com/MaWoScha/Unicode_FileUploader/blob/master/app/code/community/Uni/Fileuploader/controllers/Adminhtml/FileuploaderController.php they set the name to `'File-' . time() . $ext;` so they're just using the current time as the filename - not very smart

Comment: yea I figured it out too, I changed it so it uses the filename instead.